# Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name laravel after git checkout

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate, laravel-artisan

I fetched a new branch from the remote and checked out to the branch in the server.

But then I keep getting this error for every `artisan` command.

[image]

The laravel version is `5.4`.

How can I fix this?